# Program crashed in iOS5 and normal in iOS4?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios5

My game created in cocos2d 0.99.5.I tested it and released in App Store already.

After I updated my iPhone from iOS4.3.3 to iOS5.0, my game crashed so frequent.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x668a540> was mutated while being enumerated.'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x30bed8bf 0x37d921e5 0x30bed3e3 0x5cd1 0x2f837 0xa577b 0xae245 0xcc29d 0xcdfed 0x322ee423 0x322ee379 0x358d3f93 0x31e81891 0x30bb6f43 0x30bc1553 0x30bc14f5 0x30bc0343 0x30b434dd 0x30b433a5 0x33771fed 0x32bb5743 0x2c65 0x2bf8)

terminate called throwing an exception

This crash broken memory stack.After I added "objc_exception_throw" breakpoint. I found crash happening in for{} NSArray loop.

I don't know why this crash only happened is iOS5.This test of game is ready for new version and new content.I can't resolve this problem and feel dejected.

Could someone help me?

====================================

update(11/3/11):

```
    NSMutableArray *monsterArray;         // monsters information

    [gameObject schedule:@selector(gameSchedule:) interval:1.0/30];    // schedule for everything update

- (void) gameSchedule:(ccTime)_dt
{
    ...
    for ( Monster *mon in monsterArray ) // here causing crash
    {
        ...
        // check every monster state
    }
}
```

I don't know thread module of cocos2d thoroughly.In my game project, there are some CCAction do sequence action:

```
    id action = [CCSequence actions:
                    ...,
                    [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doSth:)],
                    nil];
    [object runaction:action];

- (void)doSth:(id)_sender
{
    //some selector modified object value in monsterArray

    //some selector deleted or added object in monsterArray
}
```

Whether cocos2d creat a new thread for doSth: and causing the crash ?
There are many selector which did these action(modify, delete and add) in my game project.
How can I resolve this problem?

===================================================================

update(11/4/11):

@Amorya
I checked Documents about NSCopying protocol.

[monsterArray copy] return a new NSMutableArray.New object in [monsterArray copy] run actions which like CCMove\CCSequence\CCJump will causing correct process?I don't understand.Please explain it.

@Brad Larson
I added a Symbolic breakpoint "objc_exception_throw" and find out the for{} NSMutableArray loop caused the crash.

Comment: Can you please post code that crashes.

Comment: Agree, and check the error message, which states that you are modifying an NSMutableArray while enumerating (iterating over) it. This is illegal, it may simply be that with iOS 5 or the updated compiler version that came with Xcode 4.2 this now creates a runtime error rather than silently creating a logic error that you might have missed thus far.

Comment: The easy way to determine the cause of this would be to add a breakpoint for all Objective-C exceptions and run your application under the debugger with breakpoints enabled.  That should halt at the exact point where your monsterArray is being mutated, and tell you what's triggering that.  Odds are, it's a threading issue that is finally being exposed in 5.0 on your device due to slightly different timings or orders of execution.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
for ( Monster *mon in monsterArray )
```

to

```
for ( Monster *mon in [monsterArray copy] )
```

You're not allowed to modify an array while iterating over it using fast enumeration (as LearnCocos2D mentioned in a comment). Copying the array is the simplest way to fix that without changing your code's logic.

If you're not using ARC, you'll also need to throw an `autorelease` in there.

Comment: I checked Documents about NSCopying protocol.

[monsterArray copy] return a new NSMutableArray.New object in [monsterArray copy] run actions which like CCMove\CCSequence\CCJump will causing correct process?I don't understand.Please explain it.

Comment: It returns another array with the same objects in. Try it and see if it works :)